# Grandi's series manipulation allowing me to prove 1 = 0?

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, infinity, fake-proofs

Let me start by saying I have a very basic background in math, so if I'm using the wrong terms, please feel free to point it out. I know straight away that this is wrong, I'm just curious to know where exactly.

You're probably acquainted with the famous result that $1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \dots = \frac{1}{2}$. As a quick reminder, this is how that is proven:

1. $S = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \dots$
2. $1 - S = 1 - (1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \dots)$
3. $1 - S = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - \dots$
4. $1 - S = S$
5. $S = \frac{1}{2}$

But what if we do something slightly different? Something like this, by repeatedly subtracting both sides by 1:

1. $S = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \dots$
2. $1 - S = 1 - (1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \dots)$
3. $1 - S = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - \dots$
4. $1 - 1 - S = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - \dots$ (Simplifications on the right hand side will just skip to the original form from this point on.)
5. $-S = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - \dots$
6. $1 + S = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - \dots$
7. $1 + S = S$
8. $1 + S - S = S - S$
9. $1 = 0$

I refuse to believe I managed to break math with this kind of thing, so I've been scratching my head trying to find what's wrong with that, but I'm finding it pretty difficult.

Comment: this is well known results, just look up conditional convergence ans cesaro summability.

Comment: You can define these operations to work on infinite sequences but that allows you to get some nonsensical results.

Comment: @DerekLuna, some of the results are useful e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Oazb7IWzbA

Comment: I should have clarified. You are certainly right, but it can lead to some misconceptions. As soon as one allows these operations on infinite sets the meaning of the results change in a way different from how we normally work with these operations.

Comment: instead of thinking of this as a breaking math/ thinking hard about where you might have gone wrong in calculations, this should serve as evidence that you SHOULD NOT manipulate infinite series as simply as you would with finitely many numbers. One needs to be very careful with the definitions (especially with sequences and series and limits)

Comment: I would point out that $1 \neq 1/2$ so once you've proved that you have a contradiction and now you can prove anything is true. That's the magic of accepting an absurdity.

Comment: "If you wish to discourse with me, you must define your terms" --- Voltaire. Writing "$+...$" at the end of an expression does not define anything. Until you have  a definition of $1-1+1-1+...$, you cannot assert that it is a number $S$ and not a unicorn.... $S=1/2$ is $not$ a result.